# Updating Geography Data Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
UPDATE f
SET
f.GeographyField = s.GeographyField 
FROM dbo.Table1 f 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 s on f.ID=s.ID 
WHERE 
f.ID ='12345'
```

When I run that I receive this error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 2 Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'sys.extended_index_645577338_384000' with unique index
>   'SIndx_SpatialTable_geography_col1'. The duplicate key value is
>   (0x7d41bf7704, 12345).

both s.GeographyField and f.GeographyField are geography data types. I never worked with that data type. I don't know how to query to figure out duplicate. How to fix above problem?

I can't find unique index on f.GeographyField. Moreover, I tried to query this to figure out whether there are indeed duplicates, but I can't query it. I think geography types are queried in different way

```
select * from Table1 where GeographyField = '0xE7100000010C29904D2D5Y874440F1F44A5986FE5BC0'
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the geography data type, it's telling you that the unique index would have a duplicate value in your table `Table1`. Guessing you have 2, or more, rows in your table with the `Table1` with the `ID` `'12345'`? (Also, is your ID column really a `varchar`?)

Comment: Does it say that it has unique index on f.GeographyField? I can't find that index on Table1. No, that is not varchar, I think that is not a matter here

Comment: @Larnu - I'm reading the error message as there being some sort of uniqueness constraint on (GeographyField, ID). It could be implicit because, from the docs, "Spatial indexes require the table to have a clustered primary key.". To get around this issue specifically, I'd try adding a predicate to the where clause on the update of `f.GeographyField <> s.GeographyField`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. (Comment if not working. will remove.)

got some clue from below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stastext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

```
UPDATE f
SET
f.GeographyField = geography::STGeomFromText(s.GeographyField.STAsText())
```

or

```
SET 
f.GeographyField = geography::STGeomFromWKB(s.GeographyField.STAsBinary())
```